# Connection using "socket" library

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, server

I am working on a python program which will allow me to send and receive data between PCs. I have managed to get it to work in my local network and wanted to set it up to be able to connect from the internet. I opened the port 1234 in my router and used the local IP on the server.py and puclic IP on the client, but the server.py seems to not receive any data. What am I doing wrong here?

The example code is something like this (it works for local networks, but on separate PCs only, IP address, of course, is just an example and probably will not work for anyone else):

server.py:

```
import socket
import time
import pickle


IP = "192.168.1.69"
PORT = 1234

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))

server_socket.listen()

print(f'Listening for connections on {IP}:{PORT}...')

client_socket, client_adress = server_socket.accept()
print(pickle.loads(client_socket.recv(1024)))
client_socket.send(pickle.dumps('DONE'))
time.sleep(1)
client_socket.send(pickle.dumps('boi'))

print(client_socket, client_adress)
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import pickle
import time

IP = "192.168.1.69"
PORT = 1234
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))

client_socket.setblocking(False)

client_socket.send(pickle.dumps("NICE."))
time.sleep(1)
print(pickle.loads(client_socket.recv(1024)))
time.sleep(1)
print(pickle.loads(client_socket.recv(1024)))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you actually have an external IP? Is your server reachable (e.g. via ``ping``) outside of your Python program?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I don't really understand what you mean. By external I meant public, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What he's asking is if you can ping that public IP from the PC your client program is sitting on?

Comment: Note that if you bind the server to the local IP, it is only reachable on the local IP (unless there is some NAT translating the public IP to the local one). Basically this depends 100% on your network setup, and close to 0% on your Python code.

Comment: 1. Can you ping your public IP?
2. Have you ensured your router is forwarding correctly to your PC?

Comment: When I try to ping the IP adress all the packets are alost